# Is arr[i] = i; legal?

Tags: c, array-initialization

I want to initialize a value of all array members to their index.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int arr[10];

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        arr[i] = i;
}
```

Should I consider the sequence point in this case? 
Is `arr[i] = i` legal and portable?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? You're not modifying `i` in the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider sequence points if you modify something more than once in one place, **or** if you both read and modify something in one place.

You're not doing any of that, so your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction its just assigning a value to the array index

If you just want an array of 0123456789 its fine

Although its only one line its a good practice to use {}

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
   arr[i] = i;
}
```